# Real analysis, showing that a set is not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, compactness

I am limited to theorems from Rudin, so think basic real analysis.

Given:

$l^1$ - set of sequences such that the infinite series consisting of terms $|a_n|$ converges. i.e absolute convergence. $l^\infty$- the set of sequences such that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded. $c_0$ - the set of sequences such that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Also all these sequences have terms in $\Re$.

1. Show that $d(a_n,b_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|a_n-b_n|}{2^n}$ is a distance function on these sets. I think I did this. Basically used metric on $\Re$ and triangle inequality etc, quite simple. Now it gets tricky (at least for me):
2. a) Show that the set $F=\{x\in l^\infty| d(x,0)=1\}$ is closed and bounded but not compact. b) Show that the set $F=\{x\in c_0| d(x,0)=1\}$ is closed and bounded but not compact. (This is how the problem is stated, so I think my teacher means that the metric used on $F$ must be the same as in 1. using any other metric seems nonsensical to me.)

What I have done:
I showed that they are both closed and bounded. However, compactness is non-trivial. I think I can use the fact (and negate it) that any sequence in a compact metric space converges to a point in that (compact) metric space. So since the objects in $F$ are sequences already I suppose I need to find a sequence of sequences. Correct? I Have tried this but to no avail. Does anyone have suggestions for such a sequence of sequences such that it does not converge to any point in $F$?

Any other suggestions are of course also very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

/I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $x_n$ be the sequence whose terms are all $0$ except for the $n$-th term, which is $2^n$. Show that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has no convergent subsequences — in fact, no convergent Cauchy subsequence.

(Note that compactness of a metric space doesn’t guarantee that each sequence converges: it merely guarantees that each sequence has a convergent subsequence.)

**Added:** Let me be a little more explicit:

$$\begin{align*}
x_0&=\langle 1,0,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle\\
x_1&=\langle 0,2,0,0,0,\ldots,\rangle\\
x_2&=\langle 0,0,4,0,0,\ldots,\rangle\\
x_3&=\langle 0,0,0,8,0,\ldots,\rangle\\
&\;\vdots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I kind of get that, but I guess where I am confused is as to why a set that contains sequences as objects shouldn't we have that its not the objects that converge but a sequence of them? I'm confused :(

I guess I try to picture this as when constructing $R$ out of sequences. I.e. we have sequences of sequences. Some clarification on this would have me much obliged.

Comment: @inzie: It **is** a sequence of them. $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of points of $\ell^1$, $\ell^\infty$, and $c_0$; each of those points is a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: Ah that clarification really cleared things up. Thanks!

Comment: @inzie: You’re welcome!